# Seeking suggestion On Query

Tags: t-sql

can we get as 'new Record' in  column "changed" 
  for au_id which is not present in one table and present in another table

```
CREATE TABLE authors
(
au_id VARCHAR (100),
au_lname VARCHAR (100),
au_fname  VARCHAR (100),
phone VARCHAR (100),
address VARCHAR (100),
city VARCHAR (100),
state VARCHAR (100),
zip VARCHAR (100),
[contract] VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT authors

SELECT '1', 'address', 'KALIA','29' ,'Second Avenue' ,     '9',' Second', 'Avenue','LALQUILA' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'address',  'WALIA','279' ,'Hague Way',        '79', 'Hague', 'Way','QUTUBMINAR' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'address',  'TOLIA','269', 'East Hague Street','69', 'East', 'Hague','Street'

SELECT * FROM authors
CREATE TABLE authorsCopy
(
au_id VARCHAR (100),
au_lname VARCHAR (100),
 au_Fname VARCHAR (100),
phone VARCHAR (100),
address VARCHAR (100),
city VARCHAR (100),
state VARCHAR (100),
zip VARCHAR (100),
[contract] VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT authorsCopy

SELECT '1', 'address', 'KALIA','29' ,'Second CHAIBASA' ,     '9',' Second', 'Avenue','LALQUILA' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'address',  'WALIA','279' ,'Hague Way',        '79', 'Hague', 'Way','QUTUBMINAR' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'address', 'TOLIA', '269', 'East Hague Street','69', 'East', 'Hague','Street' UNION ALL
SELECT '4', 'address', 'MIR', '279' ,'TATANAGAR',        '79', 'Hague', 'Way','QUTUBMINAR' UNION ALL
SELECT '5', 'address', 'WANGDU', '269', 'GHATSILA','69', 'East', 'Hague','Street' 

SELECT * FROM authorsCopy


DECLARE  @temp TABLE(au_id VARCHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY) /*this holds the primary keys of rows that have changed */
INSERT INTO @Temp(au_ID) --determine which rows have changed
  SELECT au_ID
  FROM --use the EXCEPT technique qhich is the quickest in our tests
  (
  SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname, phone, [address], city, state, zip, [contract]
    FROM authors
        EXCEPT
  SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname, phone, address, city, state, zip, contract
    FROM authorsCopy
  )f--now we just SELECT those columns that have changed
SELECT lefthand.au_id,lefthand.name,lefthand.value AS original,Righthand.value AS changed
  FROM (--now we just lay out the two tables as key value pairs, using the string versions of the data
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'au_lname' AS 'name',au_lname AS 'value'
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'au_fname' AS 'name',au_fname AS 'value'
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'phone',phone
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'address',address
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'City' AS 'name',City AS 'value'
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'State',state
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'zip',zip
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authors.au_id, 'contract',CONVERT(CHAR(1),contract)
    FROM authors LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authors.au_id) LeftHand
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'au_lname' AS 'name',au_lname AS 'value'
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'au_fname',au_fname
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'phone',phone
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'address',address
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'City' AS 'name',City AS 'value'
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'State',state
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'zip',zip
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id
    UNION
  SELECT authorsCopy.au_id, 'contract',CONVERT(CHAR(1),contract)
    FROM authorsCopy LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Temp altered ON altered.au_id=authorsCopy.au_id) rightHand
      ON lefthand.au_ID=righthand.au_ID
    AND lefthand.name=righthand.name
  WHERE lefthand.value<>righthand.value
```

Comment: can we get value something like  'new Record' in column "changed" for au_id which is not present in one table and present in another table. may some one suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqldemon, I'm not going to pretend that my solution is eloquent or fancy as there are certainly going to be other ways to achieve the same result. That said, as you wrote your code in declarative SQL and you're not using functions or stored procedures, I'm going to assume you're looking for something simple and straight-forward. Below is query that will return bit values allowing you to identify which records from the Authors table are new and which ones have been changed in some way and identify the columns that changed. You can turn the final select statement into another CTE or load its results into a temporary table and use it to return whatever works best for you (e.g., new values side-by-side with old values).

```
With New_Records as (
Select c.au_id

From #authorsCopy c
    Left Outer Join #authors a
        on a.au_id = c.au_id

Where a.au_id is null
)

Select a.au_id
    , CAST(Case
        When n.au_id is not null
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as new_record
    , CAST(Case
        When c.au_id is not null
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as changed_record
    , CAST(Case
        When a.au_fname <> c.au_Fname
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as au_fname_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.au_lname <> c.au_lname
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as au_lname_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.address <> c.address
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as address_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.city <> c.city
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as city_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.state <> c.state
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as state_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.phone <> c.phone
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as phone_diff
    , CAST(Case
        When a.contract <> c.contract
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as bit) as contract_diff

From #authors a
    Left Outer Join New_Records n
        on a.au_id = n.au_id
    Left Outer Join #authorsCopy c
        on a.au_id = c.au_id
            and (a.au_fname <> c.au_Fname
                or a.au_lname <> c.au_lname
                or a.address <> c.address
                or a.city <> c.city
                or a.state <> c.state
                or a.zip <> c.zip
                or a.phone <> c.phone
                or a.contract <> c.contract)
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher: a great idea.

Comment: But this is not something i am looking for, just i want to know which all are modified
record and which all are new, with actual value, i am not sure whether its achievable or not. Please suggest.

Comment: Can anyone suggest something, some other query.

Comment: Will the most up-to-date version of the author's record always be in the AuthorCopy table?